# What do you call this specific table design?

Tags: information-graphics, tables, lists

Look at the pictures - Does this type of hierarchical list or table, where you start reading it from the left and the data become more and more narrow, have a common name?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's no hierarchy in those diagrams.

> Hierarchy or Visual Hierarchy is the order of the elements in the way that human eye perceives them or all the elements ranked in order of priority.

- Vertical arrangements: elements are sorted in order of rank, from largest to smallest, highest to lowest, and so on.
- Linear hierarchy: there is for each element a superior and a subordinate element, and the rank order results in a continuous sequence

The images at the question are a **Classification Chart** displayed as a table and a **Table of contents**.

Comment: I totally agree that they are not examples of visual hierarchy. But the information inside the table/list is in a hierarchical order. The listed articles in the table of content, for example, is divided into sections. Oh, well.

Comment: @TonyBolero - actually, I think Danielillo is spot on here. These two tables aren't the same, and his suggestions for common names for them are perfect, in my opinion.